# How to use case in where clause

Tags: mysql

I want to get only *status = 1* records. But I don't have status column in my table. So I derived the value using **CASE... WHEN... THEN**. But when I try to use case in where clause, It shows syntax error.

my query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *,
    CASE
        WHEN quantity > num_used AND (CURDATE() BETWEEN coupon_start_date AND coupon_end_date) THEN '1'
        ELSE '0'
    END AS STATUS
FROM
    table_coupon_code
WHERE
    (CASE
        WHEN quantity > num_used AND (CURDATE() BETWEEN coupon_start_date AND coupon_end_date) THEN '1'
        ELSE '0'
    END AS STATUS) = '1' AND coupon_status <> '2'
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

remove `AS STATUS` from where clause

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * ,
  CASE WHEN quantity > num_used AND (CURDATE( ) BETWEEN coupon_start_date AND coupon_end_date)
  THEN '1'
  ELSE '0'
  END AS STATUS
FROM table_coupon_code
WHERE 
CASE WHEN quantity > num_used AND (CURDATE( ) BETWEEN coupon_start_date AND coupon_end_date)
  THEN '1'
  ELSE '0'
  END = '1'
AND coupon_status <> '2'
```

But your `CASE` is really unnecessary. Just use your `CASE` condition as stand-alone `WHERE`condition, like

```
[...]
WHERE quantity > num_used AND
CURDATE( ) BETWEEN coupon_start_date AND coupon_end_date AND
coupon_status <> '2'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to repeat the case statement you could wrap the select in a subselect or make a view. 
Subselect is something like

```
select status 
  from (select case 
          when zip like '4321%' then 1 else 0 end as status
          from adr 
       ) t 
 where status = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nobody Suggested the HAVING Clause?

This allows you to query the selected columns, instead of the actual results. Great for using case and function calls.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have some other, more complicated query, as the one you have provided is equivalent to:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * ,
       '1' AS STATUS
FROM table_coupon_code
WHERE quantity > num_used
  AND CURDATE() BETWEEN coupon_start_date AND coupon_end_date
  AND coupon_status <> '2'
```