# Conditional where in SQL based on Value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a report whereby I can't construct the SQL programatically. I have two values that are fed into the report. The values that can be one of the following three options:

1. redeem
2. purchase
3. redeem AND purchase

The query needs to have a WHERE clause. If "redeem" is fed in, it must have:

```
... WHERE balance < 0
```

If "purchase" is fed in, it must have:

```
... WHERE balance >= 0
```

if both are fed in, this condition can be left out completely, or it can be said:

```
... WHERE balance >= 0 OR balance < 0 --> but this is redundant
```

Is there a way to apply this kind of logic in SQL? Is something like this possible in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE (if param1 = 'redeem' then 'balance <= 0)  ... etc
```

?

Comment: USe `case` in `where`, this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812276/how-to-use-case-in-where-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. You're almost there.

```
WHERE (param='redeem' and balance <=0) or (param='purchase' and balance>=0) or (param='redeem AND purchase ')
```

Comment: +1 This is the only correct answer I believe -- and here you go (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/865d1/1) (although you can probably remove the last check)

Comment: Just noe that the param = 'redeem AND purchase' part is not correct. I used: param1 = "redeem" AND param2 = "purchase" etc

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` statements in your `WHERE` clause. You can find examples [here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/15633).

I tried the following code in MySQL and it works:

```sql
SET @param = 'purchase';

SELECT * FROM TEST.ACCOUNT
WHERE CASE
    WHEN @param = 'redeem' THEN BALANCE < 0
    WHEN @param = 'purchase' THEN BALANCE >= 0
    ELSE TRUE
END;
```

Comment: -1 You need to post the relevant code here in case the link goes dead.

Comment: For this specific case, I do not believe you can use CASE statements (easily).  Please show how if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I've added code that should work... Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick?

```
WHERE 
   (purchase is not null && balance >= 0)
OR
   (redeem is not null && balance < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN param1 = 'redeem' THEN balance <= 0
```

Comment: why there is a quote before balance ?